# Improving the speed of Regex in C#

Tags: c#, regex

Is there anyway to improve the speed of this function. I use it a lot to get "ID Values" and I am thinking the  way, how I am using it, is not the best one. Thanks in advance.

```
public string GetIDValues(string Elementnummer)
        {
            StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
            int totalCount = 0;
            bool elementnummerAvailable = false;

            foreach (var line in ElementHostContent)
            {
                if(line.Contains("= " + Elementnummer + ";"))
                {
                    Regex regexElementbezeichner = new Regex(@";(\s*)\/\/ ([\w|\d].*)" );
                    var regexMatchElementbezeichner = regexElementbezeichner.Match(line); 
                    var elementbezeichner = regexMatchElementbezeichner.Groups[2].ToString();
                    sb.AppendLine(elementbezeichner);

                    elementnummerAvailable = true;
                }
                totalCount++;
            }

            if (totalCount == ElementHostContent.Count() && elementnummerAvailable == true)
                return sb.ToString().Trim();
            else
                return "/";
        }
```

Inputs:

```
= 1234; // ABC DFG HIJ (CCC)
```

Elementnummer in this case is 1234

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/238877/discussion-on-question-by-kn1ghtx-improving-the-speed-of-regex-in-c).

Answer (score 1):

You are creating a new regular expression every time you need it. This is not fast. You should move the regex variable to a static field.

```cs
private static readonly Regex regexElementbezeichner = new Regex(@";(\s*)\/\/ ([\w|\d].*)" );
```

The `Regex` class will parse your regex and convert it into an efficient state machine. If you throw it away every time, that's a significant cost.

Answer (score 0):

> Is there anyway to improve the speed

Yes. Avoid using `*` (zero to many) and use `+` (one to many). Regex is about patterns, and when the author introduces the zero, in zero to many, the regex parser has to backtrack to check **all** possibilities. This exhaustive backtracking takes up a majority of the time for the regex process.

---

This match group `([\w|\d].*)` looks like it is a prime candidate which has a lot of backtracking permutations and I would recommend refactoring it.